# SAT geometry and drawing lines

Tags: geometry

[image]
The black color represents the original problem.
Q: In the figure above, line "l" (not shown) is another line in the plane. What is the maximum number of pieces the shaded area can be divided into if line l is placed anywhere in this figure?
My attempt: The pink line represents my line "l"

A. 5
B. 7
C. 9
D. 10
E. 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the yellow line? It may not be the answer but at least has more shaded parts (9) being divided.

[image]

Comment: I see 9 shaded parts. Am I right?

Comment: yes. glad to know that.